# Slow code pandas 8 million rows

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have the following code which takes 10-15 minutes to execute. That is way too slow considering that my database is growing daily. Is there any chance to make it faster?

```
# Replace all empty lists ([], '[]') in dataframe with NaN's
df = df.mask(df.applymap(str).eq('[]'))

# Replace all zeros in dataframe with NaN's
df[df == 0.0] = np.nan

# Replace empty strings in dataframe with NaN's
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Replace all strings with value 'null' in a dataframe with NaN
df.replace('null', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This seems like it could belong on Stack Overflow as it is a specific problem.

Comment: What does your data actually look like? Is it a single column of unknown length lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the built in function `where` to help with changing multiple values based on some condition:

```
mask = df.applymap(str).isin(["[]", 0.0, "", "null"])
df = df.where(~mask, other=np.nan)
```

This is about only 25% quicker than the original code

Comment: Thanks, makes sense but I am getting an error: 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh yes, thats a bit annoying, you may have to check the string version as you did in your original code.

Answer (score 4):

Not a lot to review there;

The code is well documented and readable, the only thing I frowned at was `df[df == 0.0]`, but my Python is probably just not good enough.

In can only think of the fact that `replace` [can take a list of strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for to_replace, so you can merge the last 2 statements, which will give a speed up.

From a design perspective, all the routines writing to your database should never write empty lists, zeros, empty strings or nulls, but NaN instead. Then you would never have to run this script in the first place.

Comment: @user137913 Are you maintaining the database?